# How to differentiate GE, Optic and FC adapter/SFP?

Tags: fibre-channel, fiber, gigabit-ethernet, pci-express, sfp

I'm going through old switches laying around and find myself troubled by all the different connection types the PCI adapters and their SFP have.

I found a 10GE (gigabit ethernet?) SFP that says it's a Fiber channel (Brocade 57-0000075-01) and then I get one that says Fiber Optic (Intel   TXN310110000000) or even yet, a Cisco adapter that says optic but means both (CC2-N320E-SR (B) 110-1088-30 B0) but I cannot seem to figure out (easily) which one is which even by searching their model numbers (I have many, many more laying around, these are exemples)

Wherever I go, if I ask what is the difference between Fiber Channel and Optic says it's the same but if I ask what is Gibabit Ethernet says it's both copper or Fiber optic. I'm getting frustrated, I just want to not put a FC gizmo with the GE ones and vice-versa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GE is for Gigabit Ethernet, you got that right

FC is for Fiber Channel

Optic just means that it uses light to pass data, transceivers are either copper or optics.

A transceiver can be GE and FC. Both of these are different methods as to how the data is handled and passed through the network. There are also other methods such as Infiniband and SONET, SONET is a huge one for telecommunications.

If you do not know the difference between these, then you will most likely always be using ethernet connections.

As for your part numbers there:
57-0000075-01 is a 10G SR SFP+ transceiver that can be anything but SONET

TXN310110000000 is an SX, it is a 1GB optic and can be anything but SONET

Hope this helped!